# How to return to the worksheet a macro was called from?

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I have a macro that is duplicated on buttons on 3 worksheets which moves between worksheets and at the moment once the macro command is completed I have it set to return to the 3rd sheet every time.
Is there a command I can put in the code that would return the view to the sheet that the macro was activated on in the first place rather than a set sheet.

Comment: Save the active sheet in a variable, then, after your macro finished, select the sheet within the variable again.

Comment: My fist question would be, if you want to return to the initial worksheet, why are you leaving it? Maybe your macro could be written [without using Select nor Activate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)?

Comment: @VincentG good point. Definitely the cleaner approach.

Comment: I tend to use `with` in most of my codes but i'm finding this very complicated. It has to move rows of data to other worksheets depending on the contents of a few cells and works down the sheet in reverse order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Save the active sheet in a variable, then, after your macro finished, select the sheet within the variable again:

```
' at the start of your macro:
Dim sourceSheet as Worksheet
set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet


' at the end of your macro:
Call sourceSheet.Activate
```